# Friendly Error Report on Parse using Nearley.js

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to render user friendly parser errors using Nearley.js?

```
const parser = new nearley.Parser((bracketexpr_grammar));
parse(): void{
    try {       
        parser.feed(this._sql);
        this._rawData = parser.results[0];
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        this._errors.push(error.offset);
    }
}
```

What I tried:

- `error.offset`: Only display the line the error happened (not what I want).
- `error`: it gives me a giant error, example:

.

```
Invalid syntax at line 1 col 1:

b4d455
^
Unexpected "b"

Instead of a "b", I was expecting to see one of the following:
    A "#" based on:
        csscolor →  ● "#" hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit
    A "#" based on:
        csscolor →  ● "#" hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit
    A "r" based on:
        csscolor$string$1 →  ● "r" "g" "b"
        csscolor →  ● csscolor$string$1 _ "(" _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ ")"
    A "h" based on:
        csscolor$string$2 →  ● "h" "s" "l"
        csscolor →  ● csscolor$string$2 _ "(" _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ ")"
    A "r" based on:
        csscolor$string$3 →  ● "r" "g" "b" "a"
        csscolor →  ● csscolor$string$3 _ "(" _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ "," _ decimal _ ")"
    A "h" based on:
        csscolor$string$4 →  ● "h" "s" "l" "a"
        csscolor →  ● csscolor$string$4 _ "(" _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ "," _ colnum _ "," _ decimal _ ")"
```

Instead of that giant piece of error, I want something more simple and clean like this:

```
Invalid syntax at line 1 col 1:

b4d455
^
Unexpected "b"
```

Is is possible?

https://nearley.js.org/docs/parser#catching-errors

Answer (score 2):

In version `2.20.1` of Nearley, the Error object has an attribute `token` than can be used to simplify the message. In the example below we make use of a RegExp to traverse the `message` attribute of the error and add the expected tokens to the message.

The RegExp is based  on the observation that in Nearley JS error message, as you can see in the question above, there are many repetitions of the `A "<something>" based on:` pattern (that for named tokens changes to `A <something> token based on:`)

```js
function parseFromFile(origin) {
  try {
    const parser = new nearley.Parser(nearley.Grammar.fromCompiled(grammar));
    const source = fs.readFileSync(origin, 'utf8');
    parser.feed(source);
    let results = parser.results;
    
    if (results.length > 1) throw new Error(`Language Design Error: Ambiguous Grammar! Generated ${results.length}) ASTs`);
    if (results.length ==  0) {
      console.error("Unexpected end of Input error. Incomplete Egg program. Expected more input");
      process.exit(1);
    }
    const ast = results[0];
    return ast;
  }
  catch(e) {
    let token = e.token;
    let message = e.message;
    let expected = message.match(/(?<=A ).*(?= based on:)/g).map(s => s.replace(/\s+token/i,''));
    let newMessage = `Unexpected ${token.type} token "${token.value}" `+
    `at line ${token.line} col ${token.col}.`;
    if (expected && expected.length) newMessage += ` Tokens expected: ${[...new Set(expected)]}`;  

    throw new Error(newMessage)
  }
}
```

When executed with an erroneous input the message is simplified to:

```
➜  egg-oop-parser-solution git:(master) ✗ bin/eggc.js test/errors/unexpected-token.egg
Unexpected LCB token "{" at line 1 col 2. Tokens expected: "(","[",".",EOF
```

Another related idea with error management is to introduce in your Grammar production rules for specific error situations with an associated semantic action that deals with the error. For more info see this [section](https://ull-esit-pl-2122.github.io/practicas/egg-oop-parser.html#error-management)

Comment: Unfortunately, the link in the answer is now dead.

Comment: Fixed. The link points to the right section. April 6th 2023

Answer (score 0):

This extended error messaging is from a change to `Nearley` made in the change [User-friendly Error Reporting Feature v1](https://github.com/kach/nearley/pull/453).  It does not appear this is currently configurable. It might be worth opening an [Issue with Nearley](https://github.com/kach/nearley/issues) if you are interested in requesting this feature.

I had the same problem when upgrading to a version with this new feature.  As a workaround it is possible to override the error-reporting to use the prior implementation, although this is not documented and could break especially when upgrading `Nearley`.

```
  const parser = new Parser(...);
  // Nearley error message has been extended to show all possible correct parses.
  // As a workaround, previous implementation has been overwritten here instead.
  // When Nearley allows turning off this extended error messaging, remove this workaround.
  parser.reportError = function(token) {
    var message = this.lexer.formatError(token, 'invalid syntax') + '\n';
    message += 'Unexpected ' + (token.type ? token.type + ' token: ' : '');
    message +=
      JSON.stringify(token.value !== undefined ? token.value : token) + '\n';
    return message;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are using `moo.js`, you have a built-in support for unexpected or unimplemented tokens.
After declaring your lexer, simply add the last token as

```
{
    match: /./,
    error: true,
}
```

What this does is it sets any symbol or set of symbols not intended at a particular place to throw an error pointing to the position of the error.